# How to shoot while moving in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have been noticing a strange thing in all my games where my player stops shooting if i move whether it be that the player is already shooting when i move, or the player is already moving when i try to shoot, if i move, shooting stops. Heres is a code i used to move the player in one of the recent game i made:

```
def move(self):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        self.x += self.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        self.x -= self.speed
```

And for shoot i do this:

```
     def handle_events():
          if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
          game.bullets.append(Bullet())
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Also a sidenote: If anyone knows about something in code in general that can cause this(since its happening in all my games), plaeses comment so i can update the question with relevent code, since right now i have no idea what might be causing this.

Edit: Something i recently noticed is that the player can still shoot when it is being being pulled down by gravity(which is technically still moving). So i am guessing that something happens while im pressing keys (any key, not just the onnes i have included in the code), which renders the player unable to shoot.

My `handle_evnets()` function literally just handles closing game and mouse button press. Heres the code anyway:

```
   def handle_events():
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                game.bullets.append(Bullet())
```

Heres the bullet class which gets added to `game.bullets` if `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`

```
class Bullet:
        def __init__(self):
            self.pos = [(player.x - 10 - scroll[0]), (player.y + 15 - scroll[1])]
            self.height = 3
            self.width = 20
            self.bullet = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height)).convert_alpha()
            self.bullet.fill((255, 255, 255))
            self.dir = [(mouse.x - (player.x - 10 - scroll[0])),  (mouse.y - (player.y + 15 - scroll[1]))]
            self.distance = math.hypot(self.dir[0], self.dir[1])
            self.dir = [(self.dir[0]/ self.distance), (self.dir[1]/ self.distance)]
            angle = math.degrees(math.atan2((-self.dir[1]), self.dir[0]))
            self.bullet = pygame.transform.rotate(self.bullet, (angle))
            self.speed = 10
```

Here is Game class and what happens to bullet after its added to this class which is `shoot_bullet()` function.

```
 class Game:
    def __init__(self):
    self.bullets = []


    def shoot_bullet(self):
        for bullet in self.bullets:
            bullet.pos[0] += bullet.dir[0] * bullet.speed
            bullet.pos[1] += bullet.dir[1] * bullet.speed
            D.blit(bullet.bullet, (bullet.pos[0], bullet.pos[1]))
```

Comment: This isn't possible to answer without seeing how `move()` and `handle_events()` link together

Comment: Move is not handeled by  handle_events() function (its done by "pygame.key.get_pressed()") so i guess there is no link between them but as for bullet which is handled by handle_event function, i have updated the question

Comment: Are both `move()` and `handle_events()` *always* called in the main loop?  I would also print the `Bullet.pos` when a bullet is created.  Maybe bullets *are* firing, but somehow they're off-screen.  When is `scroll[]` updated?

Comment: I tried printing bullet.pos while while  moving but it dosent show anything, since the "game.bullets" list is empty. I think what its really comming down to is "pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN" dosent work if any key is being pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think what its really comming down to is "pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN" dosent work if any key is being pressed.

No. The issue is related to the variable `events`:

> ```py
> def handle_events():
>    for event in events:
>        #[...]
>
>        if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
>            game.bullets.append(Bullet())
> ```

The above function access the variable `events` in globale name space, but that list doesn't seem to contain the events at all.
Somewhere in your code you do `events = pygame.event.get()`. But that is probably in the scope of a function or method. That causes that a new variable `events` in local name space is generated and the global variable `events` is not updated.

You have 2 possibilities to solve the issue. Either add an argument `handle_events` and pass `events` to `handle_events`:

```py
def handle_events(events):
    for event in events:
        #[...]

        if event.type ==  pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            game.bullets.append(Bullet())
```

or ensure that the variable `events` in global namespace is set, when the events are get, by using the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt).
Where aver you do `events = pygame.event.get()`, add `global events` right before:

```py
global events
events = pygame.event.get()
```